# Can I run multiple Linux instances within a RHEV-M VM?

Tags: virtualization, rhev, paravirtualization

My overlords have allocated me one VM and externally-routable IP for use on a certain project, and I've since discovered that the software that runs on this is essentially a singleton (no more than 1 instance running) and darn it, I have to have about 8 of them. So I could go back to the overlords and say "Hey, I need 2 more VMs maybe 3" but if I ask for 8, my ears will hurt for a week.

So maybe I can set up a VM running within a VM. Sort of like "Zones" within BSD. I know enough about XEN to know this might be possible. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: I could also modify the source code of said application. But that would be far more dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RHEV can [support nesting](http://blog.jebpages.com/archives/ovirt-on-ovirt-nested-kvm-fu/) however, for this to be configured, your "overlords" need to do the setup first.

What you can do instead, if your VM has the resources, is use containers inside it. LXC and Docker come to mind, with Vagrant lagging behind (it requires vbox, which is still doable). If the app supports it, I'd even try and make do with a simple `chroot`

Comment: `chroot` wont work because the app uses shared-memory via IPC calls.

Comment: Note to self: https://github.com/gem/oq-engine/wiki/Installing-LXC-on-CentOS